# Backend order with paypal payment method

Tags: magento2, orders, paypal, backend

I configured paypal and it's working fine on frontend, but I also need to create orders on backend. But I can't choose paypal as a payment method. Why is that?

Other methods are available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was rewriting the core, but I don't know if will appear some trouble after that.

I saw that Magento calls that function before render a payment method:

```
protected function _canUseMethod($method)
{
    return $method && $method->canUseInternal() && parent::_canUseMethod($method);
}
```

So I just rewrited for:

```
protected function _canUseMethod($method)
{
    return $method;
}
```

Magento calls that function for every method that are enabled, for disabled methods it doesn't even call it. So I think it's okay for my situation.